# How to handle Mutliple annotation/pinpoint click event in titanium framework?

Tags: android-mapview, titanium

I have made an application in titanium framework for Google Maps.  I have multiple locations on the map and which are shown as annotaion/pinpoints.  I have taken click event of the annotation as well.  Annotaions will show data in tableview in the next screen.when I am coming back to the Google Maps screen, I have to click back button twice rather than once.

Queries :

1) can any body help me out how to handle the back event which should come back by 1  click only instead of 2 clicks and which should not render the data 2 times on 2 clicks of back button.Here same screen appears 2 times for data on back button event.

2) If i have many annotations on the map, then how to get the information of the same/particular pinpoint/annotation  , when it does the click event and should show data of pinpoint as tableview in the next screen.(i.e. if i have FOR LOOP and from that loop when it shows us the multiple annotation/pinpoint, all the annotation should get all the details and should shown its own data to the next screen tableview.)

Any useful  code or link will be appreciated...!!!

**I have given code snippet below :**

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var annotation = evt.annotation;
    var title = evt.title;
    var clickSource = evt.clicksource;
    // alert(annotation + 'tit'+title+'clickSource'+clickSource);
    // alert("Btn Pressed");

    if(evt.clicksource == 'rightButton') {
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("latitude",latitude.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("longitude",longitude.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("city",city.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("address",address.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("OwnerInstitution",OwnerInstitution.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("TerminalDesc",TerminalDesc.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("State",state.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("Zip",Zip.item(0).text);
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("Charge",Charge.item(0).text);

    var tab = Titanium.UI.currentTab;
        var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
            url:'ATMDetails.js',
            title:'ATM Details',
            // latitude:win1.latitude
        });
        tab.open(win1, {
            animated:true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Issue 1** I am not getting your point correctly.

**For Issue 2-** As i understand, you want to show the detail of particular annotaion where the user clicked.
**Solution:**
The function where you load all the  information using for loop define an array which should store the data of specific anotaion. like

```
annotations = []; //updated
for (i=0; i < yourfeedsData.length; i++) {

      var detailData= [];

        //Your data
         var latitude =   latitude.item(0).text;
         // all list of your data .......


        // creating annotaions 
        var annotaion = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation( { 
                 title:'Your title',
                animate:true
            });  

      // pushing the data to array ..... all your values like,
      detailData.push({lat:latitude,...... });

      // setting data to your annotaion object
      annotaion.detailData=detailData; 

      // creating annotation array
          annotations[i] = annotaion ; //updated
     }

    your_mapView.addAnnotations(annotations); // updated
```

and in your click event, get the annotation data and pass it to detail your window. And use that detail data to show in list.

```
 // get the detail data
    var detailData = evt.annotation.detailData;
 if(evt.clicksource == 'rightButton') {

                var tab = Titanium.UI.currentTab;
                var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                    url:'ATMDetails.js',
                    title:'ATM Details',
                    //latitude:win1.latitude
                });
               // PASS THE DATA TO YOUR WINDOW  
               win1 .detailData = detailData;

                tab.open(win1, {
                    animated:true
                });

}
```

Comment: 1)
annotaion.detailData=detailData;
Above code annotation.detailData is not exist. Can you please guide me how to fetch the array using annotation and to store it.?

I have tried it ,but i am getting (undefined) reply. can you please give some light on it...??

2) detailData.push({lat:latitude,...... });
Above code having {lat:latitude}..what is the use of {lat}..i think may be this is the key and {latitude} is the value. But i have tried to display {lat} value , but it is also undefined..latitude is exist and i have checked it into alert..

I need the resolution for above both of the queries

Comment: @Mishal: If you try some answer and it does not work either use comments or append your attemps to the question and point people towards that update. ([Link to your edit which has been rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/49856))

Comment: @Mishal, are you creating all the annotations in for loop and adding it to the map correctly?

Comment: yes...i am adding all the annotations in the for loop and also i can see my annotations as pinpoint on the googlemap. But i am not able to get the details for the annotations using given solution....             Hope you are getting what i want to convey...thanks for fast reply....

Comment: @Mishal, for 2nd question: Yes lat is key and latitude is value, you need to get that data in your ATMDetails.js file like this: var data = Titanium.UI.currentWindow.detailData; var latitude= data[0].lat;

Comment: <code>// setting data to your annotaion object
  annotaion.detailData=detailData; 

  // creating annotation array
  annotations[i] = station; //updated </code>                                                                     can you please explain whether above code functionality is exist or not?? {annotation.detailData}  is not available...what is the proper code for it??                                                                       In the very next line what is {station}??                   I am getting undefined for both of the above code...i want to take index annotation click.

Comment: annotaion.detailData means we are just setting a variable detailData to annotation which will help us in getting the detail of that specific location for which the annotation is being created. It is just like setting windows variable

Comment: Actually it was annotations[i] = annotaion not annotations[i] = station.

Comment: Hi thanks for fast reply....But still i am not able to get data for <code>annotaion.detailData</code> ..      Once i will able to get data for it than on click event <code>evt.annotaion.detailData</code>..is possible ...Actually detailData is not the property of annotation than how <code>annotation.detailData</code> is possible??? please give some resolution for it...thanks..A

Comment: Did you try alert(evt.annotation.detailData); ? Does it show any thing?

Comment: One more thing, Are you adding the annotaions array to your map after the for loop just like i mentioned in my example or not? <code> your_mapView.addAnnotations(annotations);</code>